# Dynamic database data type validation

Tags: c#, database, validation, csv, web

I've searched for a couple of hours trying to get some answers or guidelines or general practices for this issue but I could not find anything... anyways I thought someone might be able to help so feel free to pitch in or mention any useful blogs, libraries etc...

What I'm trying to do is to dynamically parse CSV files and map them to a database table. However it is not a single table, this is a generic tool to be used to import data from a CSV file into any data table.

The issue is to do with validation. I want to make sure that the contents of the CSV are valid in terms of database Data Types.

For example lets say I have the following CSV file:

[image]

and I have a database table with the following fields:

VARCHAR(32), NUMBER (OR INT), DATE

In the following example, I will need to make sure that the CSV contents are valid, so I will need to make sure that the name is actually a 'string' and is bound by the data length (32 which could be BYTES or CHAR at least in Oracle) and whether it can be null or not, and so on for the other fields. (this is also done on client side)

Now what I can do is query the data table for its columns and attributes (DATA TYPE, DATA LENGTH, NULLABLE...) and send that data to the client and then in the client I could have in **simplest terms** a switch statement that will check the data type and then perform the appropriate validation.

However I'm looking for something that is better and more scalable since it isn't practical to check for each and every data type in possibly multiple databases.

I know I can just try to import/insert the data and if I get any errors I can just rollback, but that is not ideal. I need to actually validate and notify the user of exactly where the error is.

Oh and by the way this is done in .NET and C# but I'm open to any help/ideas available.

Thanks

Comment: ETL tools like those built into SQL Server already check data types. All databases (you didn't specify one) allow you to get information about a table's columns, types and sizes. You *can't* know the lenght of a CSV column though without first reading *all* of the data. It may be that the very last row in a 100K row file as a name where you thought it would have a date, or a string larger than all the previous ones

Comment: I mentioned that in the question, I can get table columns and all of its attributes, but then I want to validate, for example in Oracle I can get that a column is of type NUMBER -> then what? should I just send that to the client and have a method for example that would be
` switch(response)
{
 case 'VARCHAR': 
xyzValidation();
break;
case 'NUMBER':
abcValidation();
break;
...
}`

Comment: To put it another way, 90% of every BI, Machine Learning or generally data engineering project is cleaning up. There will always be dirty files, unexpected schema changes, newlines or quotes where you expected none. You'll have to handle and remove bad data, keep working with the *good* data, generate alerts when something goes bad. You can't fix bugs that occur at 12 am on Saturday. Your ETL process should be able to work until someone comes to fix it on Monday

Comment: I did not mention this but this is actually a manual process, the user will submit a csv file... I want to show the user any invalid rows/fields what ever and then ask them to fix and then try again. so this is not some kind of job running or anything. Sorry for the confusion.